# Appfabric Azure

Tags: windows, azure, azure-appfabric

Real application how can i use this app fabric ??

How can i put my business logic in this and this logic use in my windows azure application??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Azure AppFabric is a collection of services that allow to you leverage functionality traditionally provided on premise by infrasture components common to most networks. Currently, it consists of the following:

**Azure AppFabric Service Bus** - allows for connection of applications by providing a centralized relay point in the cloud. Applications create outbound connections to the rendezvous location, thus helping mitigate the challenges posed by security measures like firewall restrictions on in-bound connections and IP masking via NAT layers. This feature includes both 'real time' options as well a 'message buffer' dynamic to allow for more disconnected style communication.

**Azure AppFabric Access Control Service** - the "ACS" allows WIF applications to quickly access various identity providers and consume a single format of claims token. Used in conjunction with products like ADFS, it allows cloud hosted applications to authenticate against on-premise identity stores.

**Azure AppFabric Cache Service** - currently in public testing, this service brings the "Velocity" style functionality to applications. This provides them with a distributed cache system as well as a new session provider.

There's more features/services coming in 2011, but these are the hot ones currently. Regarding hosting your business logic, this is not something that is currently available in the Azure AppFabric. There's been mentions that we may eventually see the potential for placing applications "on the edge", meaning the servers that front the Azure AppFabric connections, but no ETA or even firm commitment that this will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your business logic in Windows Azure, in a web or worker role depending if you need it to be synchronous or asynchronous.

You can surface the business logic using the service bus, though you could also implement your logic on premise and surface them via the service bus.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i want to make sample application with use of windows azure application , sql azure and Appfabric so is that possible three r together in one application?? if yes than tell me how?? can u provide some link or some sample code or video that i unserstand much more...

Answer (score 0):

AppFabric is not a business logic layer. Think of AppFabric as cross-cuts, or glue between different parts of your application.

For now Business logic goes in components like a web or worker role, or an on premise app which you could expose on the internet using AppFabric Service Bus.

In a future release, AppFabric will release "Composite Apps" which in a nutshell seem to allow you to deploy managed WCF/WF workflow services, which makes for a better "business engine". But for now I think you could probably just use Workflow services in a web role.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i want to make sample application with use of windows azure application , sql azure and Appfabric so is that possible three r together in one application?? if yes than tell me how?? can u provide some link or some sample code or video that i  unserstand much more...

Comment: The best place to start is to work through the labs in the Azure Training kit:    http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en     You don't have to do all of them - start with the introductory one then look at what interests you